# Decrypt large file in terminal using openssl. How to check if password is correct?

Tags: openssl

I have once encrypted a file using openssl on the command line. The result was a 135GB file. I am not sure what password I used, let alone what algorithm. The beginning of the file is `Salted__`.
When I use for example `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in fileencoded.bin -out filedecoded.bin` and enter a password it takes of course ages to see whether it was the right password. I have to cancel the decoding process and use the `head` command to output the first 10 bytes of the resulting file and see whether the output is all garbage or a valid header of my original file.

Is there an easier way to get the immediate output of the decoding result "on the fly"?

Comment: I am not use in crypto, however truncate a copy of fileenncode.bin to a small file and test. (if file is uuencoded/base64ed you may need to edit last line).

Answer (score 3):

by default openssl must decrypt to output.

## pipe

try

```
openssl enc -pass "$pass" -aes-256-cbc -d -in fileencoded.bin | head -20
```

and provide password in pass. (be aware that anyone issuing `ps` will see the password)

## small file

just issue once :

```
 head -2000 fileencoded.bin > small.bin
```

then, iterate password

```
 openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in small.bin
```